# How to translate 'subject' (of lesson) and 'teacher'?

Tags: english-to-japanese

I cannot understand how to translate 'subject' to Japanese in lesson context? E.g. Russian, mathematics and etc. are all subjects.

And I need to translate 'teacher', as in school teacher and university teacher.

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary? Or example sentences?

Comment: I have dictionary but I was not sure that my translation had correct semantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [分野]{ぶんや} and [科目]{かもく} are viable ways to translate 'subject' or 'field' in an academic sense. As far as something doubling for teacher and university 'teacher' (professor, in English), I'd recommend [教授]{きょうじゅ}.

Comment: でも・・・「教授」って大学の先生/教員だけですよね。。。それに、大学でも「准教授」「助教」「講師」とかは「教授」じゃないし・・・小中高の先生/教員/教師/教諭とかも「教授」とは言わないし・・・